# Middleware not workign as expected in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have made middleware that checks if class exists as per url segment and conducts appropriate tasks.However before the middleware is triggered laravel catches the exception and throws error:

```
    ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class App\Http\Controllers\cms\modules\asdfasdfsadf\asdfasdfsadfController does not exist
```

if I die and dump any thing on `checkClass` middleware the value is dump only when the class exists.

My route where middleware is applied is:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => PREFIX,'middleware'=>array('auth','role','checkClass')], function () {
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'cms' . '\\modules\\' . Request::segment(2) ], function () {

        Route::get('{module}/pages/{page}', Request::segment(4) . 'Controller@index');

        Route::get('{module}', Request::segment(2) . 'Controller@index');

        Route::get('{module}/{page}', Request::segment(2) . 'Controller@' . Request::segment(3));

        Route::post('{module}/{page}', Request::segment(2) . 'Controller@' . Request::segment(3));

        Route::get('{module}/{page}/{id}', Request::segment(2) . 'Controller@' . Request::segment(3));

        Route::get('{module}/pages/{page}/{id}', Request::segment(4) . 'Controller@' . Request::segment(5));

        Route::post('{module}/pages/{page}/{id}', Request::segment(4) . 'Controller@' . Request::segment(5));

        Route::get('{module}/pages/{page}/{abc}/{id}', Request::segment(4) . 'Controller@' . Request::segment(5));

        Route::post('{module}/pages/{page}/{abc}/{id}', Request::segment(4) . 'Controller@' . Request::segment(5));
    });
});
```

Here we can see that I have dynamically created routes as per URL segment.Here is my `checkClass` middleware:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class CheckClass
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (!class_exists('App\\Http\\Controllers\\cms\\modules\\'.Request::segment(2).'\\'.Request::segment(2).'Controller')) {

                return view("errors.404");

        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Shouldn't middleware fire before laravel searches controller class as per route ?

Comment: Why would you even do this?

Answer (score 0):

The middleware are fired after Laravel finds the route since it needs to find out which middleware to use (since a route can be nested in multiple groups and such).

This error however should result in a 404 by default. Maybe check youre exception handler to make sure it does (and check with `app.debug` set to false because it then displays exceptions like this instead of just showing a 404.

Comment: where is `app.debug` ?so that I can set it to false?

Comment: It is either set in your `.env` (`APP_DEBUG`) file or you can change it directly in `config/app.php`.

Comment: nope it just disables error message but I want to catch class not found exception before route throws any error